# asp.net mvc 3 razor sections and portable areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, portable-areas

Is it possible to have a portable area feed into a ASP.Net MVC 3 razor section?  I have a section in my  for placing JS files, CSS, fiels, etc.  I want to be able to target the head section from portable areas for any JS, CSS files the portable area needs.  Is this possible?

Thanks
Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use master page concept just like _Layout.chtml to put portable sections. (It event works for header)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" 
              type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")" 
          type="text/javascript">    </script>
    @{
        //access your portable section here.
    }
</head>

<body>
    @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```